# Can I use a material other than PTFE to print PETG?

Tags: all-metal-hotend

Because of the crazy shipping prices, I want to find a cheaper alternative to ordering a 600$ all-metal hot-end.

Is there a material like that which does what PTFE does but till higher temperatures?

Comment: An all-metal hotend shouldn't be more expensive than a 10$ heat break.

There are variants of the PTFE tube (e.g. by Capricorn) that support higher temperatures (~260) that should suffice easily for PETG.

Comment: a genine e3D v6 costs about 70 €.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PETG does not need an all-metal hotend or alternate bowden/lining material. Unless you're trying to print at [`#speedboatrace`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zkKcFtLAks)-competitive speeds, the recommended print temperature range for PETG is 230-250 °C, and the temperature above which you should not use a PTFE-lined hotend is 250 °C.